# Image blur not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, blur

I am trying to have a blur effect with an image on Internet Explorer (8, 9 and 10)

HTML

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
     <filter id="blur" x="0" y="0">
       <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" />
     </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>   

<img class="svg-only-blur" src="http://css-plus.com/examples/2012/03/gaussian-blur/i/fence.jpg" />
```

CSS

```
.svg-only-blur {
  filter: url(#blur); 
}
```

Other solutions I tried can be found here, none of them is working
=> http://jsfiddle.net/mottalrd/zM673/

However this is indeed possible, as you can see from here
=> http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_svg-filter-effects.htm

What I am doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Which IE browsers have you tested in? Don't SVG filters only work in IE10+?: http://caniuse.com/svg-filters

Comment: Tested on 9 and 10. According to your link it should work with IE 10.